Why Does My Node.js App Time Out When Connecting to SQL Server with Windows Authentication?
I am trying to connect to a SQL Server instance from a Node.js application using Windows Authentication, but I'm encountering a connection timeout error.
SQL Server Version: SQL Server 2019
Port: 1433
And TCP enabled on Server Configuration Manager enter image description here.
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
  server: "D15\\SQLEXPRESS",
  database: "DBToDo",
  port: 1433,
  options: {
    encrypt: false,
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    connectTimeout: 30000 // 30 seconds
  },
  authentication: {
    type: "default",
    options: {
      trustedConnection: true // Using Windows Authentication
    }
  }
};

sql.connect(config, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Database connection error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully connected to the database!');
  }
});


What is the server topology on your node app vs your sql server? Also, combining port and instancename is wrong already.

You may need to change "d15" to a fully qualified server name  such as "d15.mydomain.com"
